# How to truncate large file on osx?

Tags: linux, macos

I have a 500mb file. I want to keep only the first 5 mb. How can I truncate it on osx where the 'truncate' command isn't available (and can't be installed by homebrew)?

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truncate_a_file#Python

Comment: If disk space is not an issue, you could just take first 5Mb from the file with dd(1): `dd if=/some/path/500mb of=/tmp/5mb bs=1M count=5`.

Comment: Looks like it's gone again. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/truncate

Answer (score 6):

1. Install truncate

   `brew install truncate`
2. Truncate a file to 0 size:

   `truncate -s 0 your_filename`

Comment: Seems like `truncate` has been removed from brew: `Error: truncate has been disabled because it has a removed upstream repository!` [Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/truncate)

Answer (score 4):

You should probably try to use this - The null device /dev/null act as the black hole that discards all data written to it under Unix like operating system. You can try to use it as follows :

cp /dev/null largefile.txt
OR
cat /dev/null > largefile.txt

whichever goes right, must be the right thing to do in future.

Comment: I like this better since it's done without a separate tool

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but as of Oct 2018 you can install it via homebrew:

```
> brew info truncate
truncate: stable 0.9 (bottled), HEAD
Truncates a file to a given size
https://www.vanheusden.com/truncate/
/usr/local/Cellar/truncate/0.9 (4 files, 49.3KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-10-31 at 14:54:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/truncate.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 281 (30 days), 861 (90 days), 3,138 (365 days)
install_on_request: 283 (30 days), 862 (90 days), 3,124 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Update from 2022, September:

```
 ╰─ brew info coreutils
 ==> coreutils: stable 9.1 (bottled), HEAD
 GNU File, Shell, and Text utilities
 https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils
 Conflicts with:
  aardvark_shell_utils (because both install `realpath` binaries)
  b2sum (because both install `b2sum` binaries)
  ganglia (because both install `gstat` binaries)
  gdu (because both install `gdu` binaries)
  idutils (because both install `gid` and `gid.1`)
  md5sha1sum (because both install `md5sum` and `sha1sum` binaries)
  truncate (because both install `truncate` binaries)
  uutils-coreutils (because coreutils and uutils-coreutils install the same binaries)
 Not installed
 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/coreutils.rb
 License: GPL-3.0-or-later
 ==> Dependencies
 Required: gmp ✘
 ==> Options
    --HEAD
    Install HEAD version
 ==> Caveats
 Commands also provided by macOS and the commands dir, dircolors, vdir have been installed with the prefix "g".
 If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH with:
  PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
 ==> Analytics
 install: 86,771 (30 days), 265,204 (90 days), 1,257,918 (365 days)
 install-on-request: 62,729 (30 days), 190,281 (90 days), 885,118 (365 days)
 build-error: 132 (30 days)
```

Comment: not work anymore Error: truncate has been disabled because it has a removed upstream repository!

Comment: Then... use what that error message says, and maybe try installing `coreutils` which *is* available?

Answer (score -1):

```
: > filename
```

The colon means true and produces no output and therefore nothing is redirected to the file--thus overwriting all of it contents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: having a little issue with `sudo :> file.log` ...